# Where to initialize member variables of Class in C++

Tags: c++

I just started using C++. I have a question. Where should I initialize class member variables? I have assigned some value to members variables using some member function. But static analysis tool is complaining about member initialization in constructor. See following example:

test.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point {
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Point(int r)
    {
      y = r;
    } 

    inline void setXval(int x_val) {
       x = x_val;
    }
};
```

Here, that tool says that x is not initialized in constructor. But I am setting x value in member function. Is it correct way to do this or we should always initialize all members in default constructor? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Here's a good definition of that class: `struct Point{ int x, y; };`. Keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks @Cheersandhth.-Alf. I know that but for learning purpose I am asking. What is wrong in that approach ?

Comment: It only adds verbosity. Additionally it can prevent some optimizations. So it's negative value.

Comment: Sure @Cheersandhth.-Alf. That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variables should get an explicit value in the constructor.  You're not giving any value to `x`, so your tool is correct.  You might or might not call the member function that sets the value for `x` later - You cannot count that you (or a user of your code) will call that function before you need the value of `x` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Brick. I got your point. This is precisely what I am looking for. I will mark this post as solved. Appreciate it !

Answer (score 2):

Your tool want that you use initializer list:

```
class Point {
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should construct every class member in a constructor. 
Member functions can change class members' values, but it can't construct them.

```
Point(int _x, int _y): x(_x), y(_y) {}
```